# SQL: How To Query my customers who made a purchase after 6 months of registering with us?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, metabase

I have a table that I can pull up that shows daily if a customer made a purchase or not and the values are 0 or 1 for the day with the list of customers.

Table = Customers_daily,
column = made_purchase = 1 or 0

```
Select date_utc, count(distinct customer_id), made_purchase
from customers_daily
```

If i wanted to analyze the customers who made a purchase only in their 6th month since reg_date where should i specify that?

this is the output im looking for 
[image]

Im just trying to make sure on this date_utc we are pulling the customers who are in their 6th month since registration date

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Isn't there a customer id in the table?

Comment: yes there is a customer id in the table.  I was actually thinking about doing a count(distinct customer_id)

Comment: You would need to use the registration date, so information about that field would be helpful. Also you say `customers who made a purchase only in their 6th month since reg_date`, but this does not match the example output at all.. please provide a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b65b3fd/1

```
SELECT date_utc, 
       count(distinct customer_id), 
       MAX((date_utc >= reg_date + INTERVAL 5 MONTH) AND (date_utc <= reg_date + INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
FROM customers_daily
GROUP BY customer_id
```

The only thing I can't get is `count(distinct customer_id)` - it will always return 1, since I `GROUP BY customer_id`?

But if you want to `GROUP BY date_utc` - than what `made_purchase` meaning over many different customers?

Please provide sample of raw data and expected result.